# Setup title and vertical list in nested tables 4 columns across

Tags: html, html-table

I need to show a Group Title on one line, then a Personal Title on the second line and then a vertical list of peoples names under that in nested tables.

I need to show four columns on each row.

I.e. here is an example of what I want

```
IBM              DELL         IBM              DELL
President       President     President       President
Mr A             Mr D         Mr A             Mr D
Mr B             Mr E         ..               ..
Mr C             Mr F
etc..
```

How to set up HTML for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well if you want plain HTML try this code
    
try adding tr, th, td tags for more rows and columns

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

td, th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #dddddd;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>IBM</th>
    <th>DELL</th>
    <th>some other</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>President</td>
    <td>President</td>
    <td>President</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Mr A</td>
    <td>Mr D</td>
    <td>Mr someguy</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Mr B</td>
    <td>Mr E</td>
    <td>Mr someguy</td>
  </tr></table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I left out an important detail. I meant in nested tables and multiple columns. I edited the question. Sorry about that.

Comment: Yes but how to have 4 columns not one?